# How to use attributes into barplot labeling. R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I got a dataset that has the response of the following question:

"Over the last 2 weeks, have you had little interest in doing things?"

And there are several answers. I can see them with this command:

```
> attributes(base$mhealth_1)$labels
             Don't know                 Refused          Not applicable 
                     -9                      -8                      -5 
                Missing              Not at all            Several days 
                     -3                       1                       2 
More than half the days        Nearly every day 
                      3                       4
```

The data distribution:

```
> table(base$mhealth_1)

   1    2    3    4 
6601 2137  905 1759
```

So I am doing a barplot graph:

[image]

With this code:

```
ggplot(base) +
 aes(x = mhealth_1) +
 geom_histogram(bins = 30L, fill = "#B22222") +
 theme_minimal()
```

How can I use the `$labels` in the x axis?

Here is some additional information:

```
> class(base$mhealth_1)
[1] "haven_labelled" "vctrs_vctr"     "double"
```

Here's an example of the data:

```
> dput(example)
structure(list(mhealth_1 = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
2, 3), labels = c(`Don't know` = -9, Refused = -8, `Not applicable` = -5, 
Missing = -3, `Not at all` = 1, `Several days` = 2, `More than half the days` = 3, 
`Nearly every day` = 4), label = "g11 - Over the last 2 weeks, have you had little interest in doing things?", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), mhealth_2 = structure(c(1, 3, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1), labels = c(`Don't know` = -9, Refused = -8, 
`Not applicable` = -5, Missing = -3, `Not at all` = 1, `Several days` = 2, 
`More than half the days` = 3, `Nearly every day` = 4), label = "g12 - Over the last 2 weeks, have you been feeling down, depressed or hopeless", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract with `attr`ibutes.  Based on the post, it is a named vector.  Use that named vector to match and replace the values of the 'mhealth_1' to create a new column and use that for plotting

```
nm1 <-  attributes(base$mhealth_1)$labels
base$mhealth_1_lbl <- setNames(names(nm1), nm1)[as.character(base$mhealth_1)]

library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(base) +
  aes(x = mhealth_1_lbl, y = mhealth_1) +
  geom_col(fill =  "#B22222") +
  theme_minimal()
```

-output

[image]

Comment: I got this error: 

`Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (32309): x`

Comment: @JorgeParedes that error is different.  I thought your attributes would have the same length as the column values

Comment: new error: 

`Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"?`

Comment: @JorgeParedes do you need to use `geom_histogram`.  Perhapss you can do this with `geom_col()` alone

Answer (score 1):

As your data looks like survey data I would guess you probably want a barchart instead of a histogram. Additionally as your data is of class `labelled` (probably imported from SPSS via `haven`) you could convert it to a labelled factor via `haven::as_factor`.

Using some random example data try this:

```r
library(haven)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

base <- data.frame(
  mhealth_1 = haven::labelled(sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE),
                              labels = c("Don't know" = -9,
                                         "Refused" = -8,
                                         "Not applicable" = -5,
                                         "Missing" = -3,
                                         "Not at all " = 1,
                                         "Several days " = 2,
                                         "More than half the days" = 3,
                                         "Nearly every day" = 4))  
)

ggplot(base) +
  aes(x = haven::as_factor(mhealth_1)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#B22222") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]